Proper implementation of post-startup script in Vertex AI Instances
When working with Vertex AI notebooks, I was interested in creating VMs that had persistent python computing environments. With the User-Managed Notebooks, I achieved this with a Docker-image. I am returning to this with the newer Instances. My Docker image doesn't seem to work with the Instances (will post a separate question), and so I resorted to trying to use a post-startup script to perform python module installations on-the-fly during boot.
I was previously successful in implementing a post-startup script following the guidance offered here, using option 2. I am returning to this process with the Vertex AI "Instances", and it is no longer working. Could someone please answer the following?

The gcloud notebooks instances create function can take two post-startup script flags. To my knowledge, the startup-script-url metadata flag executes asynchronously during the boot process, and is not actually post startup. The separate post-startup-script flag is, as I understand it, a true post startup script, which executes after the instance has been created and booted. With the newer Instances, created using gcloud workbench instances create, the post-startup-script flag has been removed and we have only startup-script-url to work with. Other than this, I haven't found any documentation mentioning the post-startup options. Is there a replacement for the post-startup-script argument?
Related to (1.), and provided my deduction is correct, that the startup-script-url is not actually run post startup, is there a way to run a true post startup script when building an Instance using gcloud workbench instances create? Here, I am interested in running a script as if I was the end user opening up the Jupyter Lab console. The paired boot-data VMs need to be fully built and accessible (as they would from the console), before running the script.
When using a startup-script-url and following the instructions for option 2 here, is the executing user still jupyter?


Hi , It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

Thanks. Support case was opened. I'll post resolutions and/or clarifying information here when the time comes.


startup-script-url is specifically for GCE
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux
Since User Managed Notebooks and Workbench instances are GCE base, both automatically support this.


gcloud notebooks instances (User Managed Notebooks). (Have a specific proto for it)

gcloud workbench instances create (Workbench Instances)


The replacement is using metadata:
--metadata=[KEY=VALUE,...]
Reference: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.instances#gcesetup
In this case use for metadata key: post-startup-script and value your location (GCS or HTTPs path). Example: gs://test-bucket/PostStartupScript.sh

Use metadata key: post-startup-script and value your location (GCS or HTTPs path). Example: gs://test-bucket/PostStartupScript.sh

No, is root.


"the startup script runs as root"
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts/linux
Vertex post-startup-script also runs as root.
Documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/instances/manage-metadata

This works, thank you. My post-startup-script is supposed to perform pip installations, but when logging the attempts, it seems that basic commands like pip and apt-get can't be found (I'm using gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/workbench-container:latest). Is this true, or is this a root user access issue?

If you are using custom container the OS is CoS (Container OS) not Ubuntu/Debian, and I believe the PSS runs at OS level not at container level. I'm working on PSS for Colab Enterprise, where we are executing the PSS at container level. This seems to be a bug in Workbench instances+Custom container where we should run the PSS at container level, not OS. Let me discuss internally and get back to you, as workaround I can think of running docker exec payload-container 

Adding some additional information gleaned from trial and error and from a formal Google support ticket...
(1) When trying to build Workbench Instances (not Managed or User Managed Notebooks) from Docker images, you are subject to the limitations of Google's Container-Optimized OS, which does not include package managers or the like (no pip or gsutil, for example).
(2) Unlike the User Managed Notebooks, when building a Workbench Instance, the default python environment is stored on the data disk (Instances are two-disk systems, with a boot disk and a data disk). Because of this, installations into the environment only need to happen once, and not on every stop-start cycle.
(3) Per @gogasca's answer, the post-startup script flags work fine. Here is a template for a two part script. The primary script is executed by the default 'root' user. It moves a file from a GCS bucket to the Instance, and also uses EOF to dynamically create a secondary script that is executed by the 'jupyter' user. This secondary script installs GDAL (which can be finicky) and python modules onto the data disk, and into the default 'base' python (conda) environment.
#!/bin/bash

# Creating log file with proper ownership, so that you can easily identify
# points of failure in the post-startup script(s).
if [ ! -d /home/jupyter/logs ]; then
  mkdir /home/jupyter/logs
  sudo chown jupyter /home/jupyter/logs
fi
touch /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo chown jupyter /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt

# Load some files onto Instance's data disk
if [ ! -e /home/jupyter/someSubDirectory/someFile.sh ]; then
  # Transfer files from GCS bucket
  gsutil cp gs://someBucket/someFile.sh /home/jupyter/someSubDirectory/someFile.sh &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
  # Give jupyter user ownership and updated permissions
  chown jupyter /home/jupyter/someSubDirectory/someFile.sh &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
  chmod a+x /home/jupyter/someSubDirectory/someFile.sh &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
else
  echo -e "Some message here.\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
fi

# Create an EOF script to execute from within the Instance
cat << EOF > /home/jupyter/createEnvScript.sh
#!/bin/bash
# Install GDAL bindings and python module. The conda installation goes into
# the default conda environment, which is 'base'.
sudo apt-get update -y &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa -y &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin -y &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev -y &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
conda install -c conda-forge gdal -y &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
#--------------
# Install various other modules, sending them into the default 'base' environment, per <https://docs.astral.sh/uv/configuration/environment/>
sudo pip install uv &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo uv pip install earthengine-jupyter>=0.0.7 --link-mode=copy --python /opt/conda &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
sudo uv pip install earthengine-api>=0.1.418 --link-mode=copy --python /opt/conda &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
# ...other installations here...
EOF

# Execute EOF script
echo -e "Script created. Changing ownership and permissions\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
chown jupyter:jupyter /home/jupyter/createEnvScript.sh &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
chmod a+x /home/jupyter/createEnvScript.sh &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
echo -e "Executing EOF script.\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
# The user executing the primary post-startup script is 'root' (whoami  &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt).
# The user that should execute the EOF script is 'jupyter'.
su - jupyter -c 'bash /home/jupyter/createEnvScript.sh' &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt
echo -e "EOF script complete.\n" &>> /home/jupyter/logs/log.txt

After loading it into a GCS bucket (gs://someBucket/postStartupScript.sh in the template code that follows), a script like that above, can be baked into the Instance creation using the following structure:
gcloud workbench instances create someNotebookName \
--project=someProjectId \
--location=someLocation-abc \
--service-account-email=serviceAccountEmailAddress \
--network=projects/someProjectId/global/networks/primaryNetworkName \
--subnet=projects/someProjectId/regions/someLocation/subnetworks/subNetworkName \
--disable-public-ip \
--boot-disk-size=150 \
--boot-disk-type=PD_STANDARD \
--machine-type=n1-standard-4 \
--labels=env=uat \
--metadata=serial-port-enable=TRUE,use-collaborative=TRUE,env=someMetadataLabel1,group=someMetadataLabel2,host=someNotebookName,enable-guest-attributes=TRUE,report-system-health=TRUE,report-notebook-metrics=TRUE,post-startup-script=gs://someBucket/postStartupScript.sh,post-startup-script-behavior=run_once

(4) When building an Instance, selecting (a) the default settings, (i.e., do not specify use of a custom Docker container, but instead "Use the latest version", per Console workflow), is not the same as selecting (b), to use the latest Workbench-specific Docker container (gcr.io/deeplearning-platform-release/workbench-container:latest). With (a), you are using the latest version of a host image (JupyterLab on a host system), which runs on Debian 11. With (b), you are running JupyterLab out of a container, but the end user does not currently have the option to select the latest version of the Container-Optimized OS image that serves as the host in (a).
